# SQL can insert separately but cannot load as file with foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I am new to the database and am following tutorials and doing experiments. So my apology if that question turned out to be stupid.

I set up a table like that:

```
CREATE TABLE if not exists SAMPLE(
    chara   varchar(15) not null,
    Num     char(9),
    secNum char(9),
    primary key (Num),
    foreign key (secNum) references sample(Num)
) engine=innodb;
```

If I insert entries one by one:

```
insert into SAMPLE(chara, Num) values ("A", "111");
insert into SAMPLE(chara, Num, secNum) values ("B", "222", "111");
insert into SAMPLE(chara, Num) values ("C", "333");
```

It works fine. But if I load the following data with `load data infile ".../SAMPLE.txt" into table SAMPLE;`:

```
A   111 \N
B   222 111
C   333 \N
```

I got an error saying:

```
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`company`.`sample`, CONSTRAINT `sample_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`secNum`) REFERENCES `sample` (`Num`))  0.000 sec
```

I could guess it has something to do with breaking the referential integrity, but I don't know what. And I also don't know why it works with serval inserts but not with the load. Could anyone help me to understand what went wrong and how can I get rid of it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you separately inserts rows one by one, for the second insert already sees 111 row and it doesn't violate the FK
but when you are loading a file it tries to insert all rows in one batch ( transaction) , so row 111 doesn't exists just yet.